# ¿Como convertir un string a int en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente con el siguiente código.

```
 var cantidad = $tds.eq(2).find("#cant").val();
 total_bultos = parseInt(cantidad) + total_bultos;   
 document.getElementById("total_bultos").value = total_bultos;
```

Al intentar sumar los caracteres ingresados en unos campos de texto y hacer la conversión de `string` a `int` siempre me arroja el famoso `NaN` al utilizar `parseInt()` en la conversión de la variable. El resultado debe ser una suma de enteros, no una suma de caracteres.

Si pueden detectar el problema se los agradezco.

Comment: intenta usando la función Number(cantidad)

Comment: como sería la sintaxis?

Comment: `total_bultos = Number(cantidad) + total_bultos;`

Comment: no, no funciona de esa manera sigue arrojando el" NaN"

Comment: puedes mnstrar en la consola el valor de la variable cantidad?

Comment: si, la variable cantidad cambia de estado cada vez que el usuario ingresa un nuevo numero, entonces en consola muestra todos los estados. La idea es sumar cada cambio de estado, me explico: si primero ingresaron 3 entonces ese 3 lo sumo al siguiente que por ejemplo puede ser 5 entonces el resultado debería ser igual a 8

Comment: si, pero no entiendo porque aplicando el Number(cantidad) aun sigue sacando el problema

Comment: Intenta haciendo esto: parseInt(cantidad) + parseInt(total_bultos) o Number(cantidad) + Number(total_bultos), creo que debes convertir ambas variables a enteros para que la suma se haga de manera correcta

Comment: Esto es un problema bastante simple (o al menos eso parece) de JavaScript... Pero **falta información clave en la pregunta**: ¿dónde se define e instancia `total_bultos`?¿qué hay en el campo `#cant` cuando se ejecuta el código?¿cuál es el contexto del código compartido? Dale a [edit] la pregunta y crea un [mcve] pulsando en el icono `<>`. Así podremos reproducir el mismo problema que tienes y ver qué es lo que está pasando.

Comment: Tal vez total_bultos es undefined?

Comment: ya logré resolverlo con una de las respuestas de esta pregunta, gracias de igual manera

Answer (score 5, accepted):

en principio la solución seria convertir a entero las variables intervinientes mediante `parseInt()`pero primero deberías ver si estas trayendo realmente un numero puede que estés trayendo cualquier cosa validaría los valores mediante la funcion [isNaN()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

Una mejor aproximación seria

```
let cantidad = $tds.eq(2).find("#cant").val();
if (!isNaN(cantidad)) {
    total_bultos = !isNaN(total_bultos) ? parseInt(total_bultos, 10) : 0; //si es una cadena vacia o cualquier cosa que no sea numero total = 0
    total_bultos = parseInt(cantidad, 10) + parseInt(total_bultos, 10);  
    document.getElementById("total_bultos").value = total_bultos;
} else {
    console.error('Error, cantidad no valida');
}
```

Asigno 0 a `total_bultos` por defecto si no es un valor numerico, porque puede ocurrir que el parametro no este inicializado, sino puedes quitar esta comprobacion`:

`total_bultos = !isNaN(total_bultos) ? parseInt(total_bultos, 10) : 0;`

Comment: ok, muchas gracias..funciona de maravilla

Answer (score 2):

Has comprobado el valor de total_bultos por consola antes de la suma?

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
 var cantidad = $tds.eq(2).find("#cant").val();
 total_bultos = parseInt(cantidad) + parseInt(total_bultos);  
 document.getElementById("total_bultos").value = total_bultos;
```

Si te fijas, hacemos parseInt de ambos valores. Usualmente lo resuelvo de esa forma para asegurarme que todo sea numérico.

Comment: sigue ocurriendo el NaN

Comment: Entonces deberias postear mas de tu código para que podamos ver exactamente donde se asigna el valor a total_bultos o de donde se obtiene.

Comment: lo tendré presente para la próxima, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te recomiendo es que siempre verifiques si los valores son numéricos con la funcion `isNaN`

Y ademas siempre ocupar `parseInt` con todos tus valores asi evitas la suma de caracteres y obtienes la suma de números.

```
if (!isNaN(cantidad) && !isNaN(total_bultos)) {
    total_bultos = parseInt(cantidad) + parseInt(total_bultos);
} else {
    console.log("Los valores no son numéricos");
}
```